# R Action Button and eventReactive not working

Tags: r, shiny

This is a simple problem, but I am not why exactly my simple button press is not displaying text.

I have an `actionButton` with id "go". When a user presses a button, I just simply want to display "Button Pressed" in my `textOutput` box. Also I want to display a message in my `R` Console window.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("go", "Go"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  displayText <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    output$text <- renderText("Button Pressed")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Right now, my GO button is displayed and right underneath I see the `TextOutput` box which has nothing in it (as expected). However, when I press the button, nothing happens. I am trying to display "Button Pressed".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `eventReactive` is not evaluated unless you use it, here I add an observe to trigger:

```
    library(shiny)
    ui <- fluidPage(
        actionButton("go", "Go"),
        verbatimTextOutput("text", placeholder = TRUE)
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {
        displayText <- eventReactive(input$go, {
            output$text <- renderText({input$go;"Button Pressed"})
        })

        observe(displayText())
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you don't return anything to `displayText`, please consider using:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("go", "Go"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text", placeholder = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$go, {
        output$text <- renderText("Button Pressed")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In the latter example, you can even remove the `observeEvent` wrapping, as you put `input$go` in the `renderText`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps! Reading the documentation, I read you could use both eventReactive or observeEvent. However, your explanation makes sense.